# What creature is Vanessa Ives?

Tags: character, penny-dreadful

What creature is Vanessa Ives from *Penny Dreadful*?

Two fallen angels want her and need her to conquer the world, she is "the mother of night", so who is Vanessa Ives? Lilith incarnation? Other fallen angel?

Answer (score 2):

[Vanessa Ives](http://penny-dreadful.wikia.com/wiki/Vanessa_Ives)
is a [Daywalker](http://penny-dreadful.wikia.com/wiki/Daywalker).

> Daywalkers are women who are knowledgeable in the occult. Although Joan Clayton implies that most daywalkers are common wood witches with knowledge of herbs and potions, she herself is proof that daywalkers can gain tremendous supernatural powers beyond brewing potions and preparing poultices. The more powerful daywalkers become, however, the more they must walk the line between good and evil, and must take care not to be seduced by darker powers.

So Vanessa Ives is a powerful human witch described as "The Mother of Evil".

Comment: In the episode "Seance", while Evelyn/Madame Kali does call Vanessa "Amunet", later in the scene, Vanessa responds with "Amunet, girl?! No, much older..." so i think she can be more then a human witch... No?

Comment: "Vanessa's nature was unclear for most of the first season, having been at first thought of as a psychic afflicted by the possession of evil spirits. However, the second season revealed that Vanessa is a witch, specifically a daywalker, having learned the arts of tarot and herbalism, and taught the Verbis Diablo by Joan Clayton. Her mentor, one of considerable strength herself, acknowledged that she has never encountered a daywalker as powerful as Vanessa."  She is a witch but she is an exceptionally powerful one.

Comment: I know she past some time with Joan and learn a lot from her and became a Daywalker but is possible she was something more,  and how explain that quote "Amunet, girl?! No, much older..."?, this not Lucifer because she are talking to madame Kali (a Lucifer witch, nightwalker) and Madame Kali is too scare of vanessa in this scene.

Comment: @Marcio.Rezende She could be but the Penny Dreadful wiki only says she is a Daywalker.

Comment: ok, but Wiki is made by fans, and that quote is very strange and point to something else...

Comment: @Marcio.Rezende Amunet was a primordial goddess in Ancient Egyptian religion. "...No, much older..." Could very well be possible. She might be reffering to Daywalkers being in existence long before Amunet.

Comment: Ok i see your point but im not agree, thanks man.

Comment: @Marcio.Rezende Didn't Vanessa say that when she was possessed? so it was the spirit who possessed her talking, not Vanessa herself

Comment: @madmada exactly, but this "spirit" is( possible) herself, every time she spoke the verbys diablo she is "possessed". So is something inside her or is herself, a ancient goddess? A fallen angel? Lilith? Or like Ocean Knight say , only a daywalker, with more power then Lucifer and a ancient egyptian god, for me is a very unreal possibility.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132866/what-made-miss-vanessa-ives-so-desirable/133478

Comment: Even you said she denied being Amunet. The answer doesn't give any relevant information if she denied being Amunet.

Comment: @OceanKnight yeah i know, i just want too add more theories. For me that question there is no full aswer, because the show dont give enough information about it, only thing for sure is , like you say, she is a daywalker but in several times the show point to something more then this. The good point of this link is when he say "Please consider all the characters in the show and their previous appereances in folklore and literature. Every character (including Dracula and Mina) has a background in our universe either in folklore and myhtology or literature." For me that is other clue.